# How to Determine Function Return Type Without Calling Function

Tags: typescript, rxjs, typescript-generics

I have an interface with the following property:

```
interface IClickable<T> {
  onClick: () => T|Observable<T>;
}
```

I want to determine in code the return type of the specified function prior to calling it. Something like this (pseudo code):

```
private result: T|null;

public onClicked(item: IClickable<T>): void {

  if item.onClick is return type T...
    this.result = item.onClick();

  elseif item.onClick is return type Observable<T>...
    item.onClick().subscribe((result) => this.result = result)

}
```

What is the correct way to perform this check prior to calling the variable function?

Comment: Your code example uses `Observable`. Do you want to tag this question as rxjs? Or [edit] the code to be a [mre] without external dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call it since only then you can determine the result type ( T or Observable). Since the Observable is a function you can distinguish them easily.

```js
  public onClicked(item: IClickable<T>): void {
    //call it 
    const subscribeOrResult = item.onClick();

    if (typeof subscribeOrResult === "function") {
      const subscribe = subscribeOrResult as (f: (item: T) => void) => void;
      subscribe((res) => this.result = res);
    } else {
      this.result = subscribeOrResult as T;
    }
  }
```

Here is [Typescript playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NroQ0m)